# Web Service call error

Tags: c#, wcf-binding

I have created a WCF Service Reference from a provided WSDL file. in C# i've created an instance of the proxy client with a basic binding and called the required method:

```
    public static bool main()
    {
        Debugger.Launch();
        var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();

        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        var remoteAddress = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://tester.mysite.de:8443/webservice/OrderNumber");

        using (var orderNumberClient = new orderNumberClient(new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport), remoteAddress))
        {
            string IDSystem = "123";
            string IDOSystem = "abc";

            //set timeout
            orderNumberClient.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10000);
            orderNumberClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
            orderNumberClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "test";

            //call web service method
            string productResponse = orderNumberClient.getNewOrderNumber(IDSystem, "01", IDOSystem); ;

            MessageBox.Show(productResponse);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Unfortunately I'm receiving a fairly unhelpful error when i call the 'getNewOrderNumber' method:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Ein Aufrufziel hat einen
>   Ausnahmefehler verursacht. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException:
>   WebService processing Exception
>
> Server stack trace:
>
> bei
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>
> bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>
> bei
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>
> ...

It's not an error on the web service side as that works fine in SOAPUI, am i possibly missing something in the binding?

Hopefully someone more knowledgable on web-services can shine a light on the root cause.

Comment: I agree this is a pretty vague exception.  I believe this particular one should have an Inner Exception that will be more helpful.  Note:  It may be nested a few layers deep.  Keep checking your Inner Exceptions until you don't have any more.

Comment: There was nothing to see of substance in the inner exception either :( luckily i found out from the client that the i was missing a required header! I'll post an answer up.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I wasn't sending the 'Authorization' header with the call. To overcome the issue I used the `OperationContextScope` class to add the required `HttpRequestMessageProperty` to the proxy instances inner channel before making the actual web service method call:

```
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(orderNumberClient.InnerChannel))
{
    var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    httpRequestProperty.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " +
    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(orderNumberClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" +
    orderNumberClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;

    string Response = orderNumberClient.getNewOrderNumber(IDSystem, "01", IDOSystem);
}
```